# Getting 502 bad request after deploying Play 2.1.0 app to Cloudbees

Tags: jenkins, java-7, playframework-2.1, cloudbees

I tried to deploy a Play app to Cloudbees (only via push to git repo from which it is built by jenkins), it compiled and should work but I get a "502 Bad Gateway" error when loading the app. There is no error shown in the console only that it answers "502 Bad Gateway" when trying to access it. But that's what I see in the browser, too.
Cloudbees say that there is no other manipulation necessary, just cloning/pulling the ClickStart-Project, making it you application and pushing it back. The Play project works fine locally.

I am very grateful for any help. Please let me know if I need to provide any other information. Thanks a lot!

Edit: It works fine with Heroku only adding a Procfile. I don't get the problem with Cloudbees...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the error is due to the database needing evolutions to be run before it can start:

```
[warn] play - Run with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true and -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true if you want to run them automatically (be careful)
Oops, cannot start the server.
@6eg39l651: Database 'default' needs evolution!
```

You can see the error in your application console: 
https://run.cloudbees.com/a/strehlst#app-manage/logs:strehlst/odzh
or via bees app:tail if you have the bees CLI installed.

You can also deploy direct from your desktop if you like:

```
play dist
bees app:deploy -t play2 dist/yourapp.zip
```

And it will push direct to your app (if you don't want a continuous deployment pipeline).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I do for both, Cloudbees and Heroku is only to push via Git to ssh://git@git.cloudbees.com/name/project.git and git@heroku.com:project.git I installed the Heroku toolbelt and it builds the application after the push, jenkins does it for Cloudbees, no errors but then when I try to access it... 502.
I would like to do it as easy as with Heroku, i.e. not having to use  any other program on the console than Git. ;)

Comment: yes - but I need your app ID/url to look further - there is an error that probably is visible in your app console from a change to the app. You should only need git, yes, that is the appeal!

Comment: @Steven your database needs evolutions:

Comment: @Steven your database needs evolutions:
[warn] play - Run with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true and -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true if you want to run them automatically (be careful)
Oops, cannot start the server.
6eg39l651: Database 'default' needs evolution!
 
You can see the error in your application console: 
https://run.cloudbees.com/a/strehlst#app-manage/logs:strehlst/odzh


So if you turn on auto evolutions - you should be off and racing (I expect this is a default between production mode that we run things in, and dev mode which Heroku do).

Comment: Thanks, Michael! I can do that locally but how do I get Cloudbees to use these parameters when running Play?

Comment: Did you fix this? How?

Comment: @smk: enabling evolutions correctly was the solution. Ideally evolutions are run separate to deployment like this, from a build job anyway.

Comment: @MichaelNeale I understand I need to manually create the tables on Cloudbees. Im getting the following the error Could not connect to MySQL server:
  Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60
You may continue if the server is simply not running.

Comment: Im trying the following mysql -h ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com -u <username> -p <password>. Im positive ive given the right creds. Any clue whats happening