# Run evolutions on cloudbees play 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1, cloudbees

Im trying to deploy an app on Cloudbees  and see the following in the logs.

```
Database 'default' needs evolution!
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:460)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:483)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:439)
```

However as suggestions  in here, [Getting 502 bad request after deploying Play 2.1.0 app to Cloudbees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900737/getting-502-bad-request-after-deploying-play-2-1-0-app-to-cloudbees),  I have set 
`applyEvolutions.default=true` using `bees:config set -a APPID`

I know i have set evolutions because when I do a bees:conflg list , I see it set.

but I still get the same error.
Im doing

- play dist
- bees deploy

What am I doign wrong?

**Update:**

Following the link @fbelz posted , Im trying to connect to mysql server on cloudbees and running into this.
Im using Mysql workbench and am sure have given the hostname , port, credentials correct.

> Connecting to MySQL server ... Lost connection to MySQL server at
>   'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 60

Comment: I know that this [example](https://github.com/michaelneale/play-example-mysql) works with evolutions. Take a look and compare with your application conf.

Comment: Your MySQL workbench can't connect to cloudbees DB?

Comment: So , I had 3 mysql instances (on my free account). Deleted the first two and then it worked. Maybe theres a limit on the free account.